# Why won't Win 8 Remote Desktop Connection connect to a workstation within a Win Server 2008 domain

Tags: desktop, remote, remote-connection

We have Win 8 (not Win 8 Pro) laptops that will connect to our Win Server 2008 machine via the domain name (xxx.domain.com), an allowed user name and PW.  But we cannot figure out how to get to any of the workstation PC within the domain.  Any time we try to use Remote Web Workplace (RWW), which works just fine from any other type PC (XP, Win 7, etc.) it just gives us an error also.  Has anyone had this problem and figured out how to make Win 8 work correctly when trying to get to a work PC from outside via the web?

Comment: Errors are not for show, it would be helpful if you could post the error message too.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to logon via RDP directly to a Windows Server machine. Only desktop OS's are supported ([Windows 8 FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/remote-desktop-connection-frequently-asked-questions)).